# Kubernetes pods (some) die after running for a day

Tags: kubernetes

We are trying a test setup with Kubernetes version 1.0.6 on AWS.

This setup involves pods for Cassandra (2-nodes), Spark (master, 2-workers, driver), RabbitMQ(1-node). Some the pods this setup die after a day or so

Is there way to get logs from Kubernetes on how/why they died?

When you try to restart died pods manually, you get some pods status as ''category/spark-worker is ready, container is creating' and the pod start never completes.

Only option in the scenario is to "kube-down.sh and then kube-up.sh" and go through entire setup from scratch.

Comment: Are you running the pods directly or are they underneath a replication controller? Are you specifying resource limits for the pods? Take a look at `/var/log/kubelet.log` on the node where the pod was running to see if it says anything interesting.

Comment: The ones that died are run directly as they are 1 instance types (like master, driver) and can not be run under replication controller. All of the above 8-pods are running with CPU="100cpu" (0.10%) on a "3-machines with 2 cores each" kubernetes cluster

Comment: Is it always the same pods that die after 1 day? Did you look in the kubelet log file to see why they failed?

Comment: Some more died today, some same and some different pods this time.  I do not see /var/log/kublet.log. I am running Kubernetes 1.0.6, is there a different location for log file?

Comment: I also noticed that these pods are on machine where *influxdb* is running (this process has high cpu usage). There were 5 pods before and only 2 new ones with replication controller came back  now (fluentd-elasticsearch, spark-worker-controller) other 3 pods - influxdb and 2 directly run ones didi not

Comment: I see this in master log(kube-controller-manager.log) podevictor.go:110] PodEvictor is evicting Pods on Node: ip-172-20-0-15.us-west-2.compute.internal. Following this line as deleting all dead pods; there is no information on what triggered this though

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl describe ${POD_NAME}` or `kubectl logs ${POD_NAME} ${CONTAINER_NAME}` should give you more information to debug.

Please also see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/application-troubleshooting.md#debugging-pods for general troubleshooting instructions.

EDIT:

After discussing in the comments, I think the problem with your node is that the node was unresponsive for >5 minutes (potentially due to high memory usage of influxdb). Node controller then deemed the node not ready and evicted all pods on the node. Note that pods managed by replication controllers would be re-created (with a different name), but pods created manually would not be recreated.

If you suspect influxdb memory usage is the root cause, you can try not running this pod to see if the problem resolves itself. Alternatively, you can change the memory limit of [influxdb container](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb/influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml#L28) to a smaller value.

EDIT2:

Some tips for finding out what happened to the node:

1. Check `/var/log/kubelet.log`. This is the easiest approach.
2. `kubectl describe nodes` or `kubectl get events | grep <node_name>` (for older version of kubernetes)

This command would give you the events associated with the node status. However, the events are flushed every two hours, so you would need to run this command within the window of time after your node encounters the problem.

3. `kubectl get node <node_name> -o yaml --watch` lets you monitor the node object, including its status in yaml. This would be updated periodically.

Comment: Tried these commands when the pod is dead. It comeback with 'error: pod "spark-driver" not found' as if that pod never existed. Not sure if there any internal logs on master though

Comment: Even if the pod died, as long as it hasn't be deleted, you should be able to access the pod through `kubectl`. Could you post the complete command you ran and the output of it?

Comment: I ran the following commands with no results: (1) ./cluster/kubectl.sh get ev ------- yields [

                FIRSTSEEN   LASTSEEN   COUNT     NAME      KIND      SUBOBJECT   REASON    SOURCE    MESSAGE]

(2)  ./cluster/kubectl.sh describe pods spark-driver --- yields 

                [ error: pods "spark-driver" not found]

Comment: Were you able to get the pod through `kubectl get pods < pod_name>` or `kubectl describe <pod_name>` _while the pod was running_? What cloud provider+os distro do you use?

Comment: I am using "debian:wheezy" docker containers on AWS provider. All docker containers killed on this specific one minion; all kubernetes "google_containers/pause" with "Exited(0)" and other application containers with  "Exited(137)". This error code seems to mean  — the container stopped with SIGKILL (137 = 128 + 9 - kill signal ). **How to find why they are getting killed?** **sudo docker inspect 47b671fe593b** gives - "State": {
        "Error": "",
        "ExitCode": 137,
        "OOMKilled": false,
    }

Comment: Could you try `kubectl describe nodes <node_name>` to see if the node in question is ready and whether there are suspicious events? In the case where the node is not ready for >5 minutes, all the pods on the node will be evicted/killed by the node controller.

Comment: That is the first thing I did. The node itself was ok but nothing in events section. I saw the pod evictions by logging into master and looking at the logs. What I noticed is that pods under rc started while manual pods did not. Could it be that the node went into not ready state and restarted rc pods? Would that be any info on why it was in that state after running for a while?

Comment: You seems to be correct. Refer to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15731 with details on latest termination. The latest node events does have **NodeNotReady** at this time. The next step is to find the cause and avoid it

Answer (score 1):

Your nodes have probably run out of disk space due to [an issue in Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13508).

An indirect fix is available in just recently released [Kubernetes v1.0.7](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.0.7).

> AWS: Create one storage pool for aufs, not two [#13803](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/13803) (justinsb)

but as described in the above-mentioned issue there's still some work to do in this area.