# Can't shut down influxDB in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb

I have spun up a Kubernetes cluster in AWS using the official "kube-up" mechanism.  By default, an addon that monitors the cluster and logs to InfluxDB is created.  It has been [noted in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068639/kubernetes-pods-some-die-after-running-for-a-day) that InfluxDB quickly fills up disk space on nodes, and I am seeing this same issue.

The problem is, when I try to kill the InfluxDB replication controller and service, it "magically" comes back after a time.  I do this:

```
kubectl delete rc --namespace=kube-system monitoring-influx-grafana-v1
kubectl delete service --namespace=kube-system monitoring-influxdb
kubectl delete service --namespace=kube-system monitoring-grafana
```

Then if I say:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
```

I do not see the pods running anymore.  However after some amount of time (minutes to hours), the replication controllers, services, and pods are back.  I don't know what is restarting them.  I would like to kill them permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to remove the manifest files for influxdb from the `/etc/kubernetes/addons/` directory on your "master" host. Many of the `kube-up.sh` implementations use a service (usually at `/etc/kubernetes/kube-master-addons.sh`) that runs periodically and makes sure that all the manifests in `/etc/kubernetes/addons/` are active.

You can also restart your cluster, but run `export ENABLE_CLUSTER_MONITORING=none` before running `kube-up.sh`. You can see other environment settings that impact the cluster `kube-up.sh` builds at `cluster/aws/config-default.sh`

Comment: Thanks much, this was exactly it.  One thing to add though because this boiled my brain for a while.  `export ENABLE_CLUSTER_MONITORING=none` does not do anything.  `export KUBE_ENABLE_CLUSTER_MONITORING=none` worked.  I had to dig through the actual kube-up sources to figure this out.